# Couldn't bypass Windows Authentication in IE version 11 selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Actually i need support from your side

Actually the app that we are trying to automate is hosted on iis and support only IE
Whever i execute the script, it requires windows authentication and to bypass this we add this url to trusted sites and enabled automatic login option in IE setting
It works fine on the same machine
However when we execute the same script on the same machine but from remote server called central it again throw an exception due to invalid credentials

Whever i execute the script, it requires windows authentication and to bypass this we add this url to trusted sites and enabled automatic login option in IE setting It works fine on the same machine However when we execute the same script on the same machine but from remote server called central it again throw an exception due to invalid credentials

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.